# Reading a CSV file and writing to a CSV file

Tags: perl, csv

```
use Text::CSV;
$csv = Text::CSV->new;
open(HIGH, "+>Hardtest.csv") || die "Cannot open ticket $!\n"; #reads the high file
while(<HIGH>)
{
    print "Printing High Priority Tickets ...\n";
    sleep(1);
    print <HIGH>;
}
close(HIGH);
```

here is my code, i am trying to read a csv and write to it, however i cant seem to read the CSV file, help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You aren't (yet) using the `$csv` that you created.

Answer (score 2):

OK, lots of things here.

1. Always `use strict` and `use warnings`.
2. You're opening the CSV file write mode (append mode?).  Don't do that, if you're just reading from it.
3. Don't use `|| die`, use `or die`.
4. Finally, don't `print <HIGH>`, instead `print $_`.

Comment: The reason to avoid printing `<HIGH>` is because the `while` already reads a line from the file, so you will only print every other line, correct?

Comment: Yes, the while loop is definitely reading the file, a line at a time (putting each line in `$_`), so printing `<HIGH>` could possible print the next line, or it might even try to print the whole file, or it might just print nothing, all of which are "bad".

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
open(HIGH, "+<Hardtest.csv") || die "Cannot open ticket $!\n"; #reads the high file
while(<HIGH>)
{
    print "Printing High Priority Tickets ...\n";
    print $_;
    sleep(1);
}
print HIGH "9,10,11,12\n";
close(HIGH);
```

Let me explain:
1. "+>" will open the file in read/write mode, BUT will also overwrite the existing file. Hence, In your code, while loop is never entered. I've changed that to "+<" which means read/write in append mode.
2. Second last statement, in above code, will append new content to the CSV file.